# Changing font inside a rich text box paragraph without changing font of the whole paragraph

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, richtextbox, paragraph

The problem may seem complicated, but I'll be the clearest possible. I need to be able to change the font **everywhere** in the text of a RichTextBox. For what I've seen so far, it is only possible to add content with a new font at the end of the paragraph. I would like to change the font **at the cursor** and start typing using the chosen font even if the cursor is **in the middle of a word**. All I could do is changing the font of the whole paragraph, taking the font of the surrounding characters or changing the font, but at the end of the paragaph. It is not a normal bahavior, and I go on thinking that doing that is ridiculously complicated...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you edit the html? Tried to add a <span style="font-family:font;"></span>?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am working with wpf and c#, not html.

Comment: Sorry, then... I missed the wpf tag and thought it was asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just have  a look at this post

[How can I change the FontFamily in a WPF RichTextBox without modifying previous text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143585/how-can-i-change-the-fontfamily-in-a-wpf-richtextbox-without-modifying-previous-t)

Comment: Wow thanks! It works. It is more work and I am not too much familiar with this particularity of the object, but iT sure is effective!